# Copy template with plugins to another hosting provider

Tags: migration

I want to copy my already existing and running Wordpress website to another hosting provider and deploy it there. I will be changing the branding and the domain name will be different.
I want to use the same website layout with the plugins under another domain name using a different hosting provider.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a detailed explanation on how to do it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

For updating the database, I recommend: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/